# Access class parents attributes from a class child

Tags: python, class, oop, object-oriented-analysis

so i have a class phone where we find the attributes : brand --> str, model--> datetime, price--> float, quantity: int

this is my code so far

the class parent

```
from datetime import datetime


class phone:
    def __init__(self, brand: str, model: datetime, price: float, quantity: int) -> None:
        self._brand = brand
        self._model = model
        self._price = price
        self._quantity = quantity

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self._brand},{self._model},{self._price},{self._quantity}'

    @property
    def brand(self) -> str:
        return self._brand

    @brand.setter
    def brand(self, brand) -> None:
        self._brand = brand

    @property
    def model(self) -> int:
        return self._name

    @model.setter
    def model(self, model) -> None:
        self._model = model

    @property
    def price(self) -> float:
        return self._price

    @price.setter
    def name(self, price) -> None:
        self._location = price

    @property
    def quantity(self) -> int:
        return self._quantity

    @quantity.setter
    def name(self, quantity) -> None:
        self._location = quantity
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jumia = phone("nokia", datetime.now(), 1200, 100)
    print(jumia)
```

i have to create a class chil magasin where i first need to create a list where i get phones from class phone then create two functions add phone to add a phone and stock() to display all phones that i have so far i'm not familiar whith oop in python can u please give me a hand of help on how can i do thaat
this is my class child , i have each class in two separated files

```
from phone import phone
from datetime import datetime


class magasin (phone):
    def __init__(self, brand: str, model: datetime, price: float, quantity: int) -> None:
        print(self.jumia
```

Comment: Instance attributes don't belong to the class; they belong to the *instance*, regardless of which class's method set the attribute.  But it's not clear from your description that you need a class that inherits from `phone`; rather, you want a class which has a list of phones as an instance attribute.

Comment: `phone` is grossly over-engineered. Your properties don't restrict what you can do with the underlying attribute, so until such time as they *do*, you might as well just make the attribute part of the public interface of the class. Later, you can replace the attribute with a more restrictive property without changing the public interface of your class.